# Pythonic style of writing a "for-loop" with "if" clause

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I use Java and I'm new to python.

I have the following code snippet:

```
count_of_yes = 0
for str_idx in str_indexes: # Ex. ["abc", "bbb","cb","aaa"]
    if "a" in str_idx:
        count_of_yes += one_dict["data_frame_of_interest"].loc[(str_idx), 'yes_column']
```

The `one_dict` looks like:

```
                                              # categorical, can only be 1 or 0 in either column

one_dict --> data_frame_of_interest -->       ______|__no_column__|__yes_column__
                                              "abc" |      1.0    | 0.0  
            \                                 "cb"  |      1.0    | 0.0  
             \                                "aaab"|      0.0    | 1.0
              \                               "bb"  |      0.0    | 1.0    
               \                              ...
                \
               other_dfs_dont_need --> ...
               ...
```

I'm trying to get `count_of_yes`, is there a better pythonic way to refactor the above for-loop and calculate the sum of `count_of_yes`?

Thanks!

Comment: You say column of interest but the structure your arrow is pointing to looks like a DataFrame? Do you have MultiIndex? If so, can you specify the levels?

Comment: You're just looking to sum the yes column then `df['yes_column'].sum()`??

Comment: @ayhan You're correct. I was wrong about the data structure. I have changed the description accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Or just index values with the letter "a" then  `df.loc[df.index.str.contains('a'), 'yes_column'].sum()`?

Comment: You can get the sum, without using a for loop, with `df.loc[str_indexes, 'yes_column'].sum()`. If that's a single DataFrame then you can just get it from the dictionary with `one_dict['df_of_interest'].loc[str_indexes, 'yes_column'].sum()`

Comment: This code is perfectly Pythonic. However, there may be a better way to run this using pandas more effectively